# Weird border around my arrow image, how can I remove it?

Tags: css, slick.js

I am using the slick slider for the our team carousel. There is a weird border around the arrow images to click the next slide.

I have tried removing all CSS effecting the arrow images, googling, stack overflow etc. How can I remove this border?!

```
$('.team-slider').slick({
    prevArrow:"<img class='slick-prev' style='background url(./img/left.svg)'/>",
    nextArrow:"<img class='slick-next' style='background url(./img/right.svg)'/>",
    dots: true
});
```

[image]

http://hedge.cloud-2.co.uk (Last page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using another HTML tag like span:

```
$('.team-slider').slick({
    prevArrow:"<span class='slick-prev' style='background url(./img/left.svg)'></span>",
    nextArrow:"<span class='slick-next' style='background url(./img/right.svg)'></span>",
    dots: true
});
```

Or Button:

```
$('.team-slider').slick({
    prevArrow:"<button class='slick-prev' style='background url(./img/left.svg)'></button>",
    nextArrow:"<button class='slick-next' style='background url(./img/right.svg)'></button>",
    dots: true
});
```

If you use button you'd have to remove the outline in CSS:

```
.slick-prev,
.slick-next{
outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Removing outline with `outline: none` is not recommended as it may create accessibility issues

Answer (score 0):

Try to add .`slick-slide { outline: none; }` to your CSS it will do the trick.

Comment: Ok I will investigate !

Comment: It is fixed now! With Ceasars solution :)